# WPF: PopUp on MouseOver of a ComboBoxItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, popup

Does anyone know of an example of how to display a PopUp on MouseOver of a ComboBoxItem?  TIA

EDIT:  I know how to create, style and position the PopUp but not how to display it!  I may be retired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we start, could you just use a tooltip?

otherwise, style the ComboBoxItem's control telmplate, include your popup in the style positioned where you want but set the Isopen property to false.

Use a trigger on mouse over to set your popup's IsOpen property to true.

[here](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=9d150a21-068f-4b99-b156-2743e8226075) is an example of using a trigger OnMouseOver

you will end up with a trigger in your style like this :-

```
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="thePopupsName"
              Property="IsOpen"
              Value="True" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
```

when the mouseOver occurs the popup will popup, when its gone the popup will return to its default value.

Comment: I need it to be interactive.  Thank you, makes perfect sense now!

Comment: actually it would be the control template triggers, not the styles

Comment: When using a ComboBoxItem, it appears that Property="IsHighlighted" is more conducive.  Some strange behaviour because as you MouseOver the PopUp, the MouseOver on the ComboBoxItem is no longer valid.