# Popup for Listview

Tags: c#, wpf

Goal:
When you have the cursor in one of of the listview's row, a pop up, with text information, should display.

If you select a new row in the listview a new text information should display.

Problem:
How should I do it? I cannot find a tutorial for it?

Information:
- The size of the popup is the same.
- I'm using C# with WPF.

[image]

Comment: Can you post relevant `DataGrid` XAML to show how and where you define `Popup`? Is it a `Tooltip`?

Comment: @FullMetalGame do you have any XAML to post ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: PopUp on MouseOver of a ComboBoxItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869497/wpf-popup-on-mouseover-of-a-comboboxitem)...  or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535010/listbox-with-pop-out-popup-item-details?rq=1

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I don't have the code. I cannot start coding when I don't know where to start.

Comment: Follow the links provided, make a start and then if you get stuck on a particular part, come back and show the relevant code. *Then* we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason a standard `ToolTip` won't do?
You can then bind text of the `ToolTip` and size of the box to any value you need.
Below an example with a single row in the `ListView`

```
    <ListView> 
        <ListView.Items>
            <ListViewItem Name="NameOfTheItem" >
                <ListViewItem.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Height="100" Width="150" Content="Some description"/>
                </ListViewItem.ToolTip>
                A row entry
            </ListViewItem>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
```